# Product label extensions in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-lables

I would like to find any extensions for Product lables for Magento2?

Comment: We can try https://github.com/boolfly/product-label

Comment: I found the Magento 2 product labels extension by FMEextensions quite feature-rich and affordable. Here is the link https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-product-labels-stickers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A.** Check in github for Product Lables. Here are some list of plugins:

1. https://github.com/wirelab/Magento2-Product-Labels
2. https://github.com/tristanbettany/Magento_2_Product_Labels
3. https://github.com/WaPoNe/module-stickers

**B.** Check in magento market place for the paid extension.

1. https://marketplace.magento.com/magebees-module-productlabel.html

The following extension is available for product lables in Magento2.

It supports upto Community 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 versions.

**C.** From Solwininfotech : (Paid version)

1. https://www.solwininfotech.com/product/magento-2-extensions/advanced-product-labels-magento-2/

**Note :**

After installing the extension, you need to run the following commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: try this MageAnts [magento 2 product labels](https://www.mageants.com/product-labels-for-magento-2.html) extension it help to your store

Answer (score 2):

You can try to find it on the github. Here are some results from the first page:

1. https://github.com/WaPoNe/module-stickers
2. https://github.com/tristanbettany/Magento_2_Product_Labels
3. https://github.com/wirelab/Magento2-Product-Labels